# Do I need a DSL splitter if my connection is internet only?

Tags: dsl, splitter

We've signed up for a internet connection that doesn't include a phone package.

Can I get away with not using a splitter?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What do you mean by "splitter"? What is it splitting? The line goes directly to your DSL modem, right?

Comment: The duplicate question has the correct answer. If your question is different, please edit it to indicate how.

Answer (score 0):

An [ADSL Splitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitter_ADSL) is usually needed only if the same line (twisted pair, usually) carries **both** the DSL signal and the normal phone line as it filters off the high frequencies of the modem from the phone line.

If you have no physical phone line (i.e. if you connect a phone to the wall socket and hear no tone) then there really is no need to use a splitter.